# Does asp.net core data protection protect the admin

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new for asp.net development; my question is how can I protect the admin from accessing confidential data stored in the database.Is it possible using **asp.net core data protection** feature;
Can anyone help me to find materials on it.
Thank you.